# Can't display modified category image file

Tags: categories, file-manager, ee3, category-image-field

I know this was addressed in older versions of EE, but I was hoping it was finally fixed in EE3.

I have a manipulation set for files in the file location. The manipulations are being made as set, but I am not able to access them through the categories tag. Is this something that is still not available within the core EE? Seems like it should just inherit the file property way like

`<img src="{kid_image:thumb}" alt="{kid}"/>`

but this doesn't work at all.

Did I miss something in the docs or is this simply not available still?

---

**EDIT**

I can retrieve everything here except the `:thumb`where "thumb" is the name of my manipulation.

Full context:

```
{exp:channel:categories
    category_group='2'
    style='linear'
    show_empty='no'
    restrict_channel='no'
}
    {category_name}
    {category_image}
    {category_image:thumb}
    {category_description}
    {category_url_title}
    {parent_id}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Comment: Can you update the question to include your full Categories tag? I'm missing some context here.

Comment: Gotcha, okay. Yes in that case you are correct, `{category_image}` does not currently support manipulations. The `{kid_image}` bit was throwing me off and I thought you might be in a categories loop inside an entries tag, etc.

Comment: No, sorry, I was just hitting a quick example. I didn't think about the confusion. Sorry.

Comment: Is there any future for this? I know it has been discussed for quite some time now. It seems like such a simple request since the file model is already doing this.

Comment: Yes, it's on our list, though I haven't looked at how involved it would be yet; that legacy code could use some refactoring which could _potentially_ make it a breaking change.